# Guardar un arreglo bidimensional creado en Php en una tabla MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Si bien hay preguntas similares respondidas, no pude resolver mi problema. He generado desde Php, un arreglo bidimensional obtenido desde una página anterior, desde donde pasé los datos por el método POST,ahora necesito guardarlos en una tabla previamente creada en MySQL. Hasta ahora realicé lo siguiente:

```
<?php
include ("datos.php");
include ("funciones.php");
$tabla=array ();
$i=0;
$j=0;
foreach ($_POST as $fila) {//guardo el POST en mi arreglo
    if($j<=9) {
        $tabla[$i][$j]=$fila;
            if($j==9) {
                $j=0;
                $i++;
            } else 
                  $j++;
    }
}
for($i=0;$i<contarFilas($tabla);$i++) {
//Muestro lo que guardé en el arreglo,verifiqué que está OK. contarFilas es una función que hace justamente "eso", no viene al caso. 
    for($j=0;$j<=9;$j++) {
        echo '<br><b>'.$tabla[$i][$j].'</b><br>';
    }
}
print_r($tabla); //para ver la estructura del arreglo.
```

Ahora quería guardarlos en una tabla MySQL de la siguiente manera:

```
for($f=0;$f<contarFilas($tabla);$f++) {
    $pasar="INSERT INTO cambios(pyp,aoi,posicion,cod_prog,cod_lista,obs_pyp,obs_aoi,agente,fecha,hora) values ('$tabla[$f][0]' ,'$tabla[$f][1]' ,'$tabla[$f][2]','$tabla[$f][3]' ,'$tabla[$f][4]','$tabla[$f][5]','$tabla[$f][6]','$tabla[$f][7]','$tabla[$f][8]','$tabla[$f][9]' )";}
    if ($conn->query($pasar) === TRUE) {
        echo "Se pasaron los datos";
    } else {
        echo "Hubo un error al pasar los datos : " . $conn->error;
 }
```

Obviamente no se puede, ya que después de investigar (hasta donde pude llegar), entendí que un arreglo no puede guardarse directamente a una tabla de MySQL sin antes convertirlo en cadena. Usando por ejemplo la función implode. si hago por ejemplo:

```
$cadena=implode("",$tabla);
echo $cadena;
```

devuelve un error, pero en cambio:

```
$cadena=implode("",$tabla[$x]);//o cualquier índice.  
echo $cadena;
```

me devuelve la fila "x" de mi tabla, con la separación que se pase como primer argumento. Pero no admite la siguiente forma:

```
$cadena=implode("",$tabla[$x][$y]);
```

Entonces. ¿Cómo podría guardar uno a uno los elementos de mi arreglo $tabla en una tabla (valga la redundancia) de  MySQL?. Espero haber sido claro, y perdón por la rusticidad del código. Soy prácticamente nuevo en esta disciplina. Saludos. Y desde ya, Gracias.

agrego como es el arreglo obtenido y que deseo guardar.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => MAITV00400 [1] => EAX67187104 [2] => 0CK104CK56A [3] => EAE61081701 [4] => C1100 [5] => [6] => [7] => Vega,Fernando_Maximiliano [8] => 6/11/2018 [9] => 7:47 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => MAITV00400 [1] => EAX67187104 [2] => 0CK104CK56A [3] => 0CC103BK5BA [4] => C1102 [5] => [6] => [7] => Vega,Fernando_Maximiliano [8] => 6/11/2018 [9] => 7:47 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => MAITV00400 [1] => EAX67187104 [2] => EAE61081701 [3] => 0CH5220K618 [4] => C1104 [5] => [6] => [7] => Vega,Fernando_Maximiliano [8] => 6/11/2018 [9] => 7:47 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => MAITV00400 [1] => EAX67187104 [2] => EAN64108201 [3] => EAN64430501 [4] => IC401 [5] => [6] => [7] => Vega,Fernando_Maximiliano [8] => 6/11/2018 [9] => 7:47 ) 
[4] => Array ( [0] => MAITV00400 [1] => EAX67187104 [2] => EAN64108201 [3] => EAN64430501 [4] => IC402 [5] => [6] => [7] => Vega,Fernando_Maximiliano [8] => 6/11/2018 [9] => 7:47 ) )
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746720/inserting-a-multi-dimensional-php-array-into-a-mysql-database

Comment: Ahí lo reviso. Gracias.

Comment: Se me ocurre que podrías guardar ese arreglo pero como tipo json...

algo asi como 
$arreglo = json_encode($array); // $arreglo sera una cadena

Comment: si pones el arreglo o como lo generas seria exelente estamos trabajando con palabras

Comment: Gracias   Elias Catalan ,  usando Json, devuelve el arreglo completo,    
separado con corchetes, resptando la estructura de la matriz, dentro de cada fila los separa con , y a su vez cada cadena esta entre "",. pero como puedo extraer cada uno de esos datos?

Comment: Que tiene por ejemplo $tabla[$f][1]?? no es un valor?

Comment: Si, tal cual, si vos haces echo $tabla[$f][1];, te muestra, dependiendo del valor de f (fila) el elemento en la columna 1. Agregué el arreglo que se genera, si haríamos echo $tabla[0][2]; mostraría 0CK104CK56A , pero así no los puedo insertar en la tabla de Mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Después de bucear bastante encontré la solución. En gran parte se la debo a Tegito123 que me recomendó una respuesta en SO en ingles. Muestro la solución:

```
<?php

 include ("datos.php");
 include ("funciones.php");
 $tabla=array ();

 $i=0;
 $j=0;

 foreach ($_POST as $fila) 
        {
                                        if($j<=9)
                            {
                            $tabla[$i][$j]=$fila;
                                if($j==9)
                                   {
                                    $j=0;
                                    $i++;}

                                    else $j++;
                            }
                        }

                        for($i=0;$i<contarFilas($tabla);$i++)
                        {
                            for($j=0;$j<=9;$j++)
                            {
                                echo '<br><b>'.$tabla[$i][$j].'</b><br>';
                            }
                        }
```

Hasta aquí generé mi arreglo a partir de lo obtenido por POST. Ahora simplemente voy a guardar el arreglo en la base de datos, y se lo hace ingresando en cada campo como una columna del arreglo original.

```
if (conectarBase ($host,$usuario,$clave,$base))
{
 foreach($tabla as $data){

 $query = "INSERT INTO cambios (pyp,aoi,posicion,cod_prog,cod_lista,obs_pyp,obs_aoi,agente,fecha,hora)
    VALUES ('$data[0]', '$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]')";

    //echo $query;die;
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        //exit;
     }
}else {echo "No se pudo conectar con la base"; }
?>
```

Saludos y gracias a todos por sus aportes. Dios los bendiga.